# MysQL - set DESC LIMIT from variable

Tags: mysql

I need to set `DESC LIMIT` using a variable. I tried the following but it gave me a syntax error.

Also is there a way to not to use the same query twice? Notice **SELECT itemid FROM items WHER hostid = 1234 AND key_ LIKE '%online%'** is used twice.

```
SELECT count(itemid) INTO @var1 FROM items WHERE hostid = 1234 AND key_ LIKE '%online%';
```

Then

```
SELECT sum(value) from (SELECT value FROM history_uint WHERE itemid 
IN (SELECT itemid FROM items WHER hostid = 1234 AND key_ LIKE '%online%') ORDER BY clock 
DESC LIMIT @var1) src;
```

Error: Syntax error near '@var1';

Comment: No can do limit has to be a constant.You could build a dynamic sql query or use row_number

Comment: can you give me an example for both? not sure how make use of row number in place for DESC LIMIT. I have to sum at the end and at the end `value` should return only one column and one row

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible directly but as [p-salmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon) mentioned in comment, it is possible through dynamic SQL query OR Stored procedure.

Here is the stored procedure I used as a test.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getTotalUsers()
BEGIN
-- DECLARE VARIABLE_NAME shouldn't be the same as any column_name within the stored procedure.
DECLARE LIMIT_ROWS INT;  

SELECT count(itemid) INTO @LIMIT_ROWS FROM items WHERE hostid = 1234 AND key_ LIKE '%online%';

PREPARE STMT1 FROM

"SELECT sum(value) from (SELECT value FROM history_uint WHERE itemid 
IN (SELECT itemid FROM items WHER hostid = 1234 AND key_ LIKE '%online%') ORDER BY clock 
DESC LIMIT ?") src";
-- The ? gets replaced by variable @LIMIT_ROWS
EXECUTE STMT1 USING @LIMIT_ROWS;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```